# UITableView not scrolling while adding on google mapView iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, uitableview

I've added a `UITableView` added in xib of a `UIViewController`.and I'm adding this VC as a subview of google map by click on marker.I've tried things in `viewDidLoad` method of my VC-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    aTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
     aTableView.bounces = YES;

      aTableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     aTableView.delegate=self;
     aTableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

and this is my `didTapMarker` method of  `GMSMapViewDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker1
{
   MYViewController *aViewController = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:towerInfoVC.view];
    return YES; 
}
```

if I add this VC on another VC as subview instead google map then scrolling works.I've searched over google but didn't find any luck.Please tell what i'm doing wrong in case of google map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your application on an iPad you should present your TableView from a [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)